# How to reset input value after clicking submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './StockQuotes.css'; 
import { createMuiTheme, withStyles, makeStyles, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import stockData from '../util/stockData';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getStocksOwned } from '../slices/stocksOwnedSlice';

const StockQuotes = () => {

    const [sharesToBuy, setSharesToBuy] = useState(stockData);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
    const handleChange = (event, index) => {
        stockData[index].owned = parseInt(event.target.value);
        setSharesToBuy(stockData);
    }
    
    const handleClick = (event, index) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(getStocksOwned(sharesToBuy));
        stockData[index].owned = 0;
    }

    const StyledTableCell = withStyles((theme) => ({
        head: {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
            color: theme.palette.common.white,
        },
        body: {
            fontSize: 14,
        },
    }))(TableCell);

    const StyledTableRow = withStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
            '&:nth-of-type(odd)': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
            },
        },
    }))(TableRow);

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        margin: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
        },
        table: {
            minWidth: 700,
            },
    }));

    const classes = useStyles();

    const theme = createMuiTheme({
            palette: {
                primary: {main: '#00e676'},
            },
        });

    return(
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="customized table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <StyledTableCell>Stock Name</StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right">Current Price</StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right">Shares</StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right">Order</StyledTableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                {stockData.map((stock, index) => (
                    <StyledTableRow key = {index} >
                        <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                            {stock.name}
                        </StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right">${stock.price}</StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right"><input type="number" onChange={event => handleChange(event, index)}></input></StyledTableCell>
                        <StyledTableCell align="right">
                            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.margin} onClick={event => handleClick(event, index)}>
                                    BUY
                                </Button>
                            </ThemeProvider>
                        </StyledTableCell>
                    </StyledTableRow>
                    ))}
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    )
}

export default StockQuotes;
```

I'm trying to get stockData[index].owned to 0 after I click submit button. Usually straight forward, but this time 8 input fields are created through mapping stockData json file which contains 8 objects. So if I put value property by input tag then type, entire 8 input field changes. So I coded this way except after I click, I get "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'owned' of object '#'". What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

A few things going on here:

1. `stockData` appears to just be an initial value for setting the component state. Once state is initialized, update and read from `sharesToBuy` so those changes flow to your component tree.
2. Don't mutate objects/state. That can cause bugs and prevent your component from updating properly. Instead, create a new copy with updated values.
3. Make your `input` controlled and update the `value` based on state changes.

```js
// Convenience function for updating state.
const updateOwnedValue = (index, owned) => {
  // Instead of mutating the array/object, create a copy with the updated values
  // and then update state so the changes flow down to your components.
  const newState = sharesToBuy.map((stock, idx) => (
    idx === index ? { ...stock, owned } : stock
  ));

  setSharesToBuy(newState);
};

const handleChange = (event, index) => {
  updateOwnedValue(index, parseInt(event.target.value));
}

const handleClick = (event, index) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  dispatch(getStocksOwned(sharesToBuy));
  updateOwnedValue(index, 0);
}

...
// Iterate over component state instead of the imported value.
{sharesToBuy.map((stock, index) => (
  ...
  <input
    type="number"
    onChange={event => handleChange(event, index)}
    value={
      // This makes your input a controlled component.
      // The value will respond to state changes.
      stock.owned
    }
  />
  ...
))}
```

Comment: The moment I type in a number in input field, I get this error "sharesToBuy.map is not a function", but object value for 'owned' updates correctly under sharesToBuy state. I just need to solve why I get that error msg as soon as I type in single number.

Comment: Oops you're right. I made `sharesToBuy` an object, but I realize now it should be  an array. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Clearing an Input

In order to reset the input upon hitting submit, you want the input to be a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).  This means that is gets its value from you passing it a `value` prop rather than storing it locally.  Your handler for the submit event is then tasked with setting that value to 0.

Material UI supports both controlled and uncontrolled components so this should be an easy change, but it's made complicated by the messy control of data in your app.  Where does the this entered value come from?  Which value needs to change in order to set it to 0?

#### Data Structure

You need to think about what data exists and where it is stored.  Data from from your json file should be used once to populate the initialState of your app or its redux store **and that's it**.

Right now you are actually mutating the `stockData` value which you imported from the json file.  This is really bad design.

You can have some information which is stored in redux and some which is stored in the local component state, but it shouldn't be the same data in both places.  The local state would be for local changes, like the number entered in the form before hitting the "Buy" button.  While the current price for each stock should be stored in redux and accessed via `useSelector`.

[This Revision](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64322076-fpd86?file=/src/App.js) isn't perfect, but hopefully it puts you on the right track.

#### Nested Components

In the demo that I linked to above you might notice that the input component loses focus when you type a character.  The reason that this happens is that you have defined the components `StyledTableCell` and `StyledTableRow` inside of your `StockQuotes` component.  That means that these components will get recreated every time that the state changes.  The input is not seen as the same input because the table cell that it's inside of is a different table cell and that's why it loses focus.

You want to define your styled components as top level components outside of your `StockQuotes` component.  (I tried just copy and pasting them outside but this introduced other errors.  As a temporary hack solution you could `useMemo` to avoid re-creation, but this is not ideal.)

Comment: For Nested Components, I see what you mean. Like you said I tried bring up sharesToBuy.map table portion above the StockQuote component then I get bunch of material ui not recognizing their table component errors. But you lead me to right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in handleClick function, at last reset your `setSharesToBuy`

as like, setSharesToBuy('');