# Input field gives me error after I type in one digit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

stockData contains JSON file which look like this [{"name":TSLA,"price":476,"owned":0},{{"name":GLD,"price":771,"owned":0}]. Currently, owned is updating correctly but problem is as soon as I type in single number, I get this error msg "sharesToBuy.map is not a function". When I console.log I get { {"name":TSLA,"price":476,"owned":3}, {"name":GLD,"price":771,"owned":0} }, which is wrong as it should be covered in array inside of curly bracket. So even when I change it so the objects are covered in an array, it won't let me type more than one digit number. What change do I need to make so input field will let me finish type full number?

```
const [sharesToBuy, setSharesToBuy] = useState(stockData);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

const updateOwnedValue = (index, owned) => {
    setSharesToBuy({
      ...sharesToBuy,
      [index]: {
        ...sharesToBuy[index],
        owned
      },
    });
  };

const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    updateOwnedValue(index, parseInt(event.target.value));
}

const handleClick = (event, index) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dispatch(getStocksOwned(sharesToBuy));
    updateOwnedValue(index, 0);
}
return (
                {sharesToBuy.map((stock, index) => (
                <StyledTableRow key = {index} >
                    <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {stock.name}
                    </StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="right">${stock.price}</StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="right"><input type="number" value ={stock.owned} onChange={event => handleChange(event, index)}></input></StyledTableCell>
                    <StyledTableCell align="right">
                        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.margin} onClick={event => handleClick(event, index)}>
                                BUY
                            </Button>
                        </ThemeProvider>
                    </StyledTableCell>
                </StyledTableRow>
)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I get sharesToBuy.map is not a function and if I put [ ] around the function, no error msg, it just breaks

Answer (score 1):

In `updateOwnedValue` when you `setSharesToBuy` you convert your state array to an object. If you are trying to update a specific element then you should map the current array to the new array.

```
const updateOwnedValue = (index, owned) => {
  setSharesToBuy((sharesToBuy) =>
    sharesToBuy.map((share, i) =>
      i === index
        ? {
            ...share,
            owned
          }
        : share
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: This helped! Only thing is after each time I type a number, I have to re-click the input field to type in next number, but I'll figure that out myself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Judoboy Alex are you still defining your styled components inside of another component?  That was the error that I explained in the third section here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64322956/10431574 The deselect happens when the competent itself gets recreated rather than just having the props changed.

Comment: @JudoboyAlex Could happen as well if the component is being remounted. I *think* using the index is ok here as I couldn't see where fields were being added/removed/changed, but you may want to use a different value for the react keys, like `stock.name` or any uniquely identifiable property of each stock object. An easy test for remounting is `useEffect(() => console.log('mounted'), []);`. If you see a bunch more than you expect then it could be part of that issue. If you find it is remounting then you'll have to climb the tree to find the ancestor that is rerending.